# running a for loop on a daterange using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe where one of the columns contains a date range from `2019-01-01` to `2019-02-01` where the format is:
`yyyy-mm-dd` Is there a way to loop over the dataframe by each day, selecting a day and then filter by that day. I would like to do some calculations on the filtered dataframe since each day has multiple records.

Since this is distributed computing, one method I came across is to insert a row number column using `row_number()` over a window of the entire dataframe and then run the for loop. But I feel that this is counterproductive, since I would be forcing the entire dataframe into a single node and my dataframe has millions of rows.

Is there a way to a for or while loop in the pyspark dataframe without using window function?

Your expert insights would be greatly welcomed!
Thank You

Comment: are you trying to create one dataframe for each day and then use it for analysis?

Comment: Yes. That is the plan

Comment: why not partition your input file by event_date and read one day of data in a for loop? the second choice is if your worker is can hold each day's data, you can use reduce_by_key, Flat map technique to do the analysis in parallel.

Comment: @E.ZY.  Thank you. I went by the partitioning method eventually. It required me to re partition my parquet file by date.
The flatmap method is interesting. That is definitely something worth taking a look.
Thanks again!